# How to write multiple conditions in a check constraint?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 3 ranks Executive, Senior and junior
I want to write a check constraint that ensures that when data is input for salary, The executive cannot have a lower salary than the senior and junior. Same thing for the other possible combinations that is Senior salary > Junior salary but not greater than executive salary.

This is what I tried but nothing is working

```
CONSTRAINT check_salary (CASE WHEN Job_Rank = 'Executive' THEN salary > (SELECT salary WHERE Job_Rank = 'Senior','Junior' END)) 

CONSTRAINT check_salary (Job_Rank = 'Executive' AND salary > Job_Rank = 'Senior','Junior' )
```

I am sure this is not correct since MYSQL is rejecting it

Comment: You should check your version of mysql and the syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: is it even possible to use a case or if inside a check statement?

Comment: ok with further research on the topic, what i really need is an assertion to specify that constraint but i don't think its possible in mysql workbench...

Comment: You might need to look into [The View WITH CHECK OPTION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-check-option.html), which allowes writing a query to be checked.

Comment: But the syntax of `CHECK (expr)` *"expr specifies the constraint condition as a boolean expression that must evaluate to TRUE or UNKNOWN (for NULL values) for each row of the table. If the condition evaluates to FALSE, it fails and a constraint violation occurs. The effect of a violation depends on the statement being executed, as described later in this section. "* as copied form @P.Salmon `expr` in  `CHECK (expr)` should also mean a query assuming you write it as a correct boolean expression